Which coupling of uniform random variables maximises the essential infimum of the sum?
Recall that a coupling of probability measures $\mu_i$ is a set of random variables $X_i$ defined on the same probability space $\Omega$ such that $X_i \sim \mu_i$.
Question: Let $\mu_1, \dots, \mu_n$ all be uniform on $[0, 1]$. What coupling maximises the essential infimum
$$I_n := \text{essinf}_{\omega \in \Omega} (X_1 (\omega) + \dots + X_n (\omega))$$
and what is the achieved value?
In particular, if we let $I^*_n$ be the optimal value, I wonder if the sequence $\frac{1}{n}I^*_n$ exhibits any kind of predictable behaviour.

Let me complete Iosif Pinelis’ answer by presenting an example for $n=3$ (in fact, it seems that a similar construction itself works for all $n$).
If $X_1<1/2$, set $X_2=1-2X_1$ and $X_3=1/2+X_1$.
If $X_1\geq 1/2$, set $X_2=2-2X_1$ and $X_3=X_1-1/2$.

Nice and elementary! Concerning the general $n$ case, you can probably generalise this construction properly, but the essential infimum can also be obtained just by coupling together all remaining pairs into deterministic random variables that always sum to $1$, as mentioned by Iosif.

That’s why I wrote only this case, yes.

Very nice! Can you disclose how you came up with this solution?

@IosifPinelis i’ve just found a desired coupling when the variables are uniform on ${0,1,\dots,d}$; then it was easy to find a continuous analogue.

@IlyaBogdanov : Did you use Mathematica or something like that for the discrete counterpart? I thought about first trying the discrete case this way, but then got distracted by other ideas, which are now seen as less fruitful.

No, I've just found a partition into triples of the form $(a,d/2+a,d-2a)$ and $(d/2+a,a,d-2a)$ ----s somehow, that was quick.,

"just found" :-) Pardon my insistence, but can you try to reconstruct the process of this finding? I want to learn more here.

Perhaps, it is just an easier version of partitioning ${0,1,\dots,d}$ into triples with the same sum (for a suitable $d$) which I was aquainted with before. I dont think I can add much more...

Note that
$$I_n^*\le E(X_1+\cdots+X_n)=n/2.$$
This upper bound $n/2$ on $I_n^*$ is attained if $n=2m$ is even and $X_{2i}=1-X_{2i-1}$ for $i=1,\dots,m$.
So,
$$I_n^*=n/2$$
for even $n$.
It also follows that
$$(n-1)/2=I_{n-1}^*\le I_n^*\le n/2$$
for odd $n$.
So,
$$I_n^*\sim n/2$$
for $\Bbb N\ni n\to\infty$.

Conjecture: $I_n^*=n/2$ for all natural $n\ge2$.
Remark 1: Obviously, $I_1^*=0$. In view of the above, it is enough to show that $I_n^*=n/2$ for all odd $n\ge3$. Moreover, in view of the above cancellations, it is enough to show that $I_3^*=3/2$.

Very slick as usual, the only remaining question is what the precise optimal configuration is for odd $n$.

@NateRiver : Isn't it odd that the odd case here is probably much harder than the even one?

Odd indeed @Iosif Pinelis. I guess even ones just cancel out whereas the odd case it’s not quite clear where to fit the extra guy…
